# Android socket programming to able to read from inputstream

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to make a messaging app using socket programming. Everything is working fine I am able to connect to the device which acts like a server with another device which acts like a client.

This is my class for Reading and writing (Same for both Server and client):

```
public class MessageReader extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private View view;
    private Activity activity;
    EditText message;
    Button send;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    private TextView textView;
    private String text;      

    public MessageReader(Socket client, View root){
        socket = client;;
         this.view = root;
         activity = (Activity)root.getContext();
    }    

    @Override
    public void run() {    
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String clientMsg;
        update("Now in MessageReader");
        message = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.yourMessage);
        send = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.send);
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);

        // will write to the output stream when send button is clicked
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                update("about to send message");
                text = message.getText().toString();
                out.println(text);
                update(text);
             }
         });

        try{
            //Code for reading from the output
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            update("waiting for a message");
            while ((clientMsg=in.readLine())!=null){
                update(clientMsg);
                updateUi(clientMsg);    
            }
            in.close();
            socket.close();
            update("Connection Closed");
        }catch (IOException e){
            update(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void update(final String msg){
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(activity,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateUi(final String message){
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I get a toast when they are connected. But I am not able to read from the input stream. I don't get any errors or exceptions or any Toasts. Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Have you start the Thread?

Comment: Yep we have started the thread

Comment: When you don't receive bytes this usually means that nothing was sent. Make sure that the data has really been sent by calling `flush()` on sender's side.